# perl-strange test behaviour

Tags: perl, testing

Excerpt from my code :

```perl
for $SS ( 0 .. scalar @TAB_SS - 1 ) {

    print Dumper ( "av", $CUMUL, $PCTVOLTMP, $TAB_SS[$SS][1] );

    $CUMUL = $CUMUL + $TAB_SS[$SS][1];
    print Dumper ( "ap", $CUMUL, $PCTVOLTMP );

    if ( $CUMUL >= $PCTVOLTMP ) {

        Calcul_Date( $TAB_SS[$SS][0] );
        $DATE  = "$Auj_j/$Auj_m/$Auj_4a";
        $HEURE = "$H:$MI:$S";

        printf(
            "%3d%-25s%8s%3s%8s\n",
            $PCTTMP, " % en volume atteints le ",
            $DATE, " à ", $HEURE );

        $PCTVOLTMP = $PCTVOLTMP + $PCTVOL;
        print Dumper ( "Prochaine étape ", $PCTVOLTMP );

        $PCTTMP = $PCTTMP + $PCT;
    }
}

printf( "Volume total sauvé : %6.2f GB\n", $TAILLC / 1000000000 );
```

For reasons I can't find, sometimes (reproducibly) the program does not enter in the test to print data as expected despite the fact that values tested are equal.

Put some print to look for something weird, but no way...

Here is what is displayed when working (only the last lines here) :

```
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4722181648752';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
$VAR4 = 92984872;
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4722274633624';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4722274633624';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
$VAR4 = '46893768708';
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4769168402332';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4769168402332';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
$VAR4 = 1699897316;
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4770868299648';
$VAR3 = '4770868299648';
100 % en volume atteints le 24/05/2016 à 07:15:40
$VAR1 = 'Prochaine étape ';
$VAR2 = '5247955129612.8';
Volume total sauvé : 4770.87 GB
```

and when not working :

```
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4325103606080';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
$VAR4 = 1119865540;
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4326223471620';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4326223471620';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
$VAR4 = '11122370688';
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4337345842308';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
$VAR1 = 'av';
$VAR2 = '4337345842308';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
$VAR4 = 89494084;
$VAR1 = 'ap';
$VAR2 = '4337435336392';
$VAR3 = '4337435336392';
Volume total sauvé : 4337.44 GB
```

Any help/clue would be very appreciated...

Comment: Without our source data, we  can't tell what's up. My thought would be - turn on `strict` and `warnings` and ensure you don't have number/string conversion problems.

Comment: This does look strange. I suggest you add `print $CUMUL >= $PCTVOLTMP ? 'oui' : 'non', "\n"` directly before your `if` statement. That will both verify the comparison and confirm that you're executing the part of the code that you think you are

Comment: @ Sobrique : my source data come from a command which is put in an array, this is why I put some print statement before my test.  @Borodin : Printing this results leads to correct responses : 'oui' when CUMUL is >= PCTVOLTMP, 'non' otherwise. So the `if`statement is correctly evaluated.

Comment: @Denis.A: So `oui` is followed immediately by `Volume total sauvé` or another `av` dump?

Comment: Yes, the test is correct. Searching in another direction (type mismatch ?), I've found that perl enquotes my numbers greater than 2^32 when displaying with `print dumper`... (why ?) Found also a big bug which was not present when processing large amount of data. In fact, my program is made to display at what time n % of saved data occurs related to total saved. I've one line per data 'saveset' which includes a termination time and the size. The bug occurs when a big save exceeds multiple n %, thus passing from 40% to 60% in one time skipping 50%... Going to solve this bug and I'll be back...

Comment: Big bug solved but test behaviour is the same. Tried declaring variables with `Math::BigInt` : no changes... Sometimes equal values are tested as equal, sometimes not. Really incompréhensible ! Running perl5.10.1 (for aix-thread-multi) on an AIX 7.1 on PowerPC 64 bits...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved !
With :

```
use bignum
```

which allows me to play with big integer values.
But as a 'collateral effect', transforms all values into float (?) thus making errors results when manipulating objects used by

```
Date::Calc
```

So, used a

```
use POSIX
```

to ceil these datas.